# how to show the image using php

Tags: php, sql-server, database, html

the image is already stored in the database. I make a php page so that I can view all the data stored in my ms sql database. it only showed the image's filename and not the actual image

```js
<?php
$serverName = "kwekwe\SQLEXPRESS";
$connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"customerdb", "UID"=>"dbadmin", "PWD"=>"kwe[enter image description here][1]" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
 //declare the SQL statement that will query the database
     $query = "SELECT * FROM Customer_Details";


 //execute the SQL query and return records
     $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query)
         or die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));

 //Show results in table

 $o = '<table border=1 id="myTable">
         <thead>
         <tr>
         <th>Customer ID</th>
         <th>Customer Name</th>
   <th>Image</th>
         </tr>
         </thead><tbody>';

      while ( $record = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result) )
          {
              $o .= '<tr><td>'.$record ['Cust_ID'].'</td>';
     $o .='<td>'.$record ['Cust_Name'].'</td>';
     $o .='<td><img height=127 width=127 src=data:image;base64>'.$record ['image'].'</td>';
     $o .='</tr>';
          }               

       $o .= '</tbody></table>';

       echo $o;
    //free result set memory
        //mssql_free_result($result);

    //close the connection
        //sqlsrv_close($dbhandle);
    ?>
```

Comment: Is the image of `BLOB` type? Or just the path to the image?

Comment: If I didn't get you wrong, you could echo the filename in src attribute of img tag instead of showing in a `<td>` element just like : `$o .='<td><img height=127 width=127 src="'.$record ['image'].'"></td>';`

Answer (score 0):

You can display it this way :

```
$o .='<td><img height=127 width=127 src="'.$record ['image'].'"></td>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try instead of

```
$o .='<td><img height=127 width=127 src=data:image;base64>'.$record ['image'].'</td>';
```

this:

```
$o .='<td><img height=127 width=127 src="data:image/png;base64,' . $record['image'] . '"></td>';
```

That should work if `$record['image']` has the base64 code of the image in it.

The reason your image is not showing currently is because `<img>` tag doesn't really have the source specified. If `$record['image']` is a file name then just generate a URL with that file name and put that in the `src=''` instead.